# Configuring Bash Script to work on other people's computers

Tags: linux, bash, homebrew

I've created a bash script that I'd like to share for other people to use
The script downloads video files, stores them in appropriate folders (which are essential to the app) and allows the user to cycle between them, using getopts so the user can send specific commands via flags

I've never done this before so I'm unsure of what "configuration" requirements I'd need to have so it works on other peoples computers. I want them to be easily able to download using homebrew or another package manager, automatically set up the required components and have them be able to use it

I know I have to create folders and a man page for them at the appropriate location. Does this require a makefile?

What other things should I be considering? My google search skills are sucking, so any links would be much appreciated

Comment: I found this https://gist.github.com/postmodern/3224049 but something with an explanation of the steps/requirements would be invaluable.

Comment: How is downloading video files related to copying system directories to `/usr/local` (as in the Makefile)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package a precompiled busybox (https://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/latest/) next to your script, and use busybox functions only.

Comment: Looks interesting, Thanks!